# Why does bad placement of toMap cause issues in RXJava?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

**Update: I'm using RxJava 1.x**

Here's the following code piece:

```
private static void tryObservableToMap() {
    bad();
    good();
}

private static void good() {
    System.out.println("GOOD CASE");
    String goodOutput =
            m(m(m(m(m(Observable.from(ImmutableList.of("a","b","c","d")), "list")
            .distinct(), "distinct")
            .flatMap(s ->
                    m(m(Observable.fromCallable(() -> getIntForString(s)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), "getInt " + s)
                            .map(intValue -> Pair.of(s, intValue)), "pair " + s)), "flatMap")
            .toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue), "toMap")
            .map(map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))), "OUTER")
            .toBlocking()
            .first();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\nOutput:");
    System.out.println(goodOutput);
}

private static void bad() {
    System.out.println("BAD CASE");
    String badOutput =
            m(m(m(m(Observable.from(ImmutableList.of("a","b","c","d")), "list")
            .distinct(), "distinct")
            .flatMap(s ->
                    m(m(m(Observable.fromCallable(() -> getIntForString(s)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), "getInt " + s)
                            .map(intValue -> Pair.of(s, intValue)), "pair " + s)
                            .toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue), "toMap " + s)), "flatMap")
            .map(map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))), "OUTER")
            .toBlocking()
            .first();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\nOutput:");
    System.out.println(badOutput);
}

private static <T> Observable<T> m(final Observable<T> observable, final String name) {
    return observable
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "subscribe"))
            .doOnError((ex) -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "error: " + ex.getMessage()))
            .doOnCompleted(() -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "complete"))
            .doOnTerminate(() -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "terminating"))
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "terminated"))
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> logRxLifecycleEvent(name, "unsubscribe"));
}

private static void logRxLifecycleEvent(final String name, final String event) {
    System.out.println("\tRXLOG " + name + " observable " + event);
}

private static int getIntForString(String s) {
    switch(s) {
        case "a":
            return 1;
        case "b":
            return 2;
        case "c":
            return 3;
        case "d":
            return 4;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The difference between good and bad is that for the bad version, I'm calling `.toMap` inside `.flatMap` instead of calling it after `.flatMap`.

If you run this code, you'll see the different events of all the observables which are part of the execution.

I'm wondering why "OUTER" observable is never terminating for the bad case. Anyone who has deeper knowledge in RX can explain?

Comment: Please provide some information about used RxJava version. Is it Rxjava 1.x?

Comment: Hans, updated the question, I'm using RxJava 1.x

Comment: can you please weed out irrelevant code? just leave the place you mean , no need for that much of code.

Comment: imho everything is relevant here. If I remove anything, then I'd run into an issue where I'm not posting a fully working example.

Comment: it doesn't have to be fully working imo, just a well representing little piece will do

Comment: The reason you get different result is because when the `toMap` is inside the `flatMap`, you are basically creating 4 distinct `HashMap`s with it, each containing a single item. At the end, you then pick the first `HashMap` having the value 1. When you use `toMap` after the `flatMap`, the operator collects all 4 items into one `HashMap` and you get that entire `HashMap` at the end.

Comment: @akarnokd I got it, but why it leads to observables being not terminated?

Comment: What exact RxJava 1 version are you using? The latest is 1.3.8.

Comment: @akarnokd exact version is RxJava-1.1.8. It won't hang, but if you go through the output of the good and the bad example, you can see the difference between them.

Comment: If I log only `OUTER`, both cases print: `RXLOG OUTER observable subscribe` and `RXLOG OUTER observable unsubscribe`. When all logs are printed, they are still there but at different points. Again, running with 1.3.8

Comment: With 1.1.8, in the good case, for OUTER i can see subscribe, unsubscribe, complete, terminating and terminated, in the bad case I only see OUTER subscribe and unsubscribe (so does not even complete)

Comment: The `RXLOG OUTER observable complete` is missing is because there is a race between `toBlocking().first()` and the source above it completing. It may get unsubscribed too soon so the source above may have no chance to emit `onCompleted`. On my i7 4770K, they never print `completed` for me. If you replace `first` with `toIterable().iterator().next()`, it gives the necessary chance and you should see the missing logs all the time.

Comment: @akarnokd can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RXLOG OUTER observable complete` is missing is because there is a race between `toBlocking().first()` and the source above it completing. It may get unsubscribed too soon so the source above may have no chance to emit `onCompleted`. On my i7 4770K, they never print `completed` for me. If you replace `first` with `toIterable().iterator().next()`, it gives the necessary chance and you should see the missing logs all the time.